# How to Query an AD user in a different domain

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have this script that will query the local domain and unlock and account if it is currently locked.   I'd like to run this same script however check a different domain.   Can I get some help with the Get=AdUser command, i thought it would be -Server "Servername" for the other domain controller however this didn't work.

---

As per the feedback given I try the below where I have put in the domaincontroller name and it doesn't seem to work as I can't unlock the locked account.  I see everything loading and I get the screen printout that it found the locked account but the account doesn't unlock.

```
$DomainController = 'domain1.local'
$AccountName = 'noctest'


 $res = Get-ADUser -Identity $AccountName -Server $DomainController - 
 Properties LockedOut | Select-Object LockedOut
 Write-Output $res

 if ($res.lockedout -eq $true)

 {
  unlock-adaccount $AccountName
  write-output  "Account has Been Un-Locked"
  exit
 }

 Write-Output "Account Not Locked."
```

Answer (score 1):

`Get-ADUser` has a -server parameter that you can use to specify a domain controller that has a particular domain's information on it, this will work assuming you have access to that other domain

```
$DomainController = 'DomainControllerName'

$res = Get-ADUser -Identity noctest -Properties LockedOut -Server $DomainController | Select-Object LockedOut

 if ($res.lockedout -eq $true)
 {
     unlock-adaccount noctest
     write-output  "Account has Been Un-Locked"
 }
```

Comment: Steve, were you able to get this to work? I didn't see your prior comment that was removed.

Comment: I updated the posting above with the changes I made as per your suggestion.  I believe it is querying the domain ok as it sees the account is locked based on following the IF statement, however it doesn't unlock the account.

Comment: Can you run the lines individually in a PS console, and see if ‘$res.lockedout’ returns anything?

Comment: FOr some reason I couldn't step through line by line.   After the $res line where it retrieves the status I added a line output and it shows the lockout to be true.  It then proceeds through the IF statement, however is no unlocking the account.

Comment: I'm not sure why you pasted your code in a comment... copy that code into a PS console, and then put in `$res.lockedout` and see if it returns anything for you

Comment: I've updated the code to what I have presently tried.

Comment: When I run the script I can see that the lockout is Enabled, however it is not unlocking the account.   Does it have anything to do with me not connected to that domain or something when I do the unlock?  I have my most recent code inputted into the initial question on the thread.